# Content page with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

We are using IE edge for our application but we want to make one particular content page should open in IE 10.

We cant add

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

to the master page because it will get reflected in all other pages.

How to implement

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

to a particular content.

I tried the following code in the content page but no change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddCompatible() {
        var m = document.createElement("meta");
        m.setAttribute("http-equiv", "X-UA-Compatible");
        m.setAttribute("content", "IE=10");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(m);
    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("AddCompatible")
```

Comment: Why can't you add it to the content page, then?

Comment: Both the javascript and <meta tag are not working when we are adding it in the content page.

Comment: Can you confirm that the JavaScript is actually updating the content page? Since it is adding the meta to document, I suspect it is actually being inserted into the master page. Once executed, you can confirm the meta tag's placement by using DOM explorer in IE's developer tools panel.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code in page_init or On_init in code behind.This code will force to IE10 compatible.

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
            tag.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
            tag.Content = "IE=10";
            this.Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, tag);
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it is not getting add to the head tag of the page.

Answer (score -3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" nonce="IICYfT/o8JWeqWwgKrYbJA">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var frameType = window.location.hash[1];
            var callbackWindow;
            switch (frameType) {
                case 't'
                FUCk:
                    callbackWindow = window.parent.opener;
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    callbackWindow = window.open('', 'gtn-roster-iframe-id');
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    callbackWindow = window.parent.frames['gtn-roster-iframe-id'];
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    callbackWindow = null;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw Error('Unknown frame type: ' + frameType);
            }
            if (callbackWindow != null) {
                callbackWindow['_GC_OnFrameReady'](window);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```